# Can a Keyboard Shortcut be Set to Connect to VPN?

Tags: vpn

I now this may sound quite lazy, but I connect to a VPN several times a day (since the laptop gets disconnected from time to time).

I am aware of the "Show VPN Status in the Menubar" option, but is there a way I can make it a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an AppleScript which would run a shell script to `racoonctl` - the specific commands will depend upon your VPN connection.  Then use Script Utility to enable the global Script Menu, then add a new keyboard shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, and assign it to the script (or use a launcher utility such as [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Automator utility and create a new "Service" workflow.
   . Set the workflow to receive "no input" in "any application" in the top-most menus.
2. Add the "Run AppleScript" action to the workflow, and replace its script contents with the following:

   ```
   tell application "System Events"
       tell current location of network preferences
           set VPN to "SERVICE NAME"
           set VPNactive to connected of current configuration of service VPN
           if VPNactive then
               disconnect service VPN
           else
               connect service VPN
           end if
       end tell
   end tell
   ```

   Be sure to replace `SERVICE NAME` with the name of your VPN connection, which can be looked up in the Network system preferences (if the name is truncated, click the Advanced... button and view the full name at the top of the Advanced Settings panel).
3. Save the workflow with a name like "Connect to VPN"
4. When this is finished, go to the Keyboard system preferences and select the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, where you can locate the "Connect to VPN" service in the Services section, and assign a custom keyboard shortcut to it. You should now be able to toggle your VPN connection on and off from within any application by using this shortcut.

I personally assign `Control + Option + Command + V' to toggle my VPN.

From [cnet](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-create-a-vpn-shortcut-in-os-x/).

Comment: This is outdated for the latest version of OS X. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38146025/5932012 for an updated bash version.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh It actually works with my latest El Capitan beta.